# Using a form and File.AppendAllText to update multiple logs

Tags: c#, forms, textbox

I'm very new to programming, so apologies if this is too simple.

I'm attempting my first program, a GUI form in C# that will use a textbox to send text to a "key" file, which will in turn start a robocopy sync. In the code I'm trying to test this with a .txt file.

from Program.cs

```
{
    string fileName = @"c:\\Test.txt";
    string textToAdd = textBox1.ToString();
    var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
    string newTime = new DateTime.Now.ToString(culture);

    //File.AppendAllText(fileName, newTime,  System.Environment.UserName, textToAdd);

    //using (StreamWriter w = new StreamWriter(fileName))
    {

        File.AppendAllText(fileName, String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", newTime, System.Environment.UserName, textToAdd));
    }
}
```

This is from the form1.cs, I'm not sure what I need to add here to get the button to work. Currently the buttons do nothing despite being set as Cancel and OK.

```
 public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     string var;
     var = textBox1.Text;
 }

 private void button_OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Form1 myForm = new Form1();

     if(myForm.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK)
     {


         MessageBox.Show("You have successfully added this entry to the key files.");
          // object MessageBoxButtons = new MessageBoxButtons;
           // MessageBoxButtons.OK = this.Close();               
     }
}

private void button_Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    Form1 myForm = new Form1();

    if(myForm.DialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
    {
         //   this.Close();
            Application.Exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by worlds : "I`m not sure what I need to add here to get the button to work " ? First part of the code - handle message format and should write message to the file. And second - just Winform with the button and text box - what it suppose to do ?

Comment: you want to append a file content with the content of the text box ?

Comment: Yes, I want the textbox to build up and add to a txt file over time, keeping a log of the additions made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you forgot to add the event handler to your method. You can do it from the editor in the button property window or in your code, with for example:

```
public Form1() 
{ 
      InitializeComponent(); 
      this.button_OK.Click+=new EventHandler(button_OK_Click); 
      this.button_Cancel.Click+=new EventHandler(button_Cancel_Click);
}
```

Anyway, your code has a lot of errors. It's a nonsense in your `button_OK_Click` that you create a new instance of `Form1` from the same form. And you should'n have any of the code you have in `Program.cs`

**Edit**

Let's analize what is wrong in your code:

### Form1

```
public void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //This does nothing. You are creating a variable whose scope is just
    // this method, so you wouldn't be able to access it from outside
    string var;
    var = textBox1.Text;
 }

 private void button_OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Form1 myForm = new Form1(); //You are creating a new Form1..Why?

     //there won't be a dialogResult,as you are not showing the form with ShowDialog
     if(myForm.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK) 
     {
         MessageBox.Show("You have successfully added this entry to the key files.");
         // object MessageBoxButtons = new MessageBoxButtons;
         // MessageBoxButtons.OK = this.Close();               
     }
}

private void button_Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
     Form1 myForm = new Form1();

     if(myForm.DialogResult == DialogResult.Cancel)
     {
     //   this.Close();
        Application.Exit();
     }
}
```

Now more or less how it should be:

First delete all the code you added to `Program.cs`. And then yout Form1 should look more or less like this:

### Form1

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.button_OK.Click += new EventHandler(button_OK_Click);
        this.button_Cancel.Click += new EventHandler(button_Cancel_Click);
    }

    private void button_OK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Add text", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {

            string fileName = @"c:\\Test.txt";
            string textToAdd = textBox1.ToString();

            string newTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");
            try
            {
                File.AppendAllText(fileName, String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", newTime, System.Environment.UserName, textToAdd));
                MessageBox.Show("You have successfully added this entry to the key files.");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There was an error adding this entry to the key files.");
            }
        }

    }

    private void button_Cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 myForm = new Form1();

        if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Exit", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Seems to work closer to what I wanted, yet its giving me an exception at the ToString here:

         string newTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("dd/MM/yy HH:mm:ss");

Non-invocable member 'ToString' cannot be used like a method.
also, a warning that 'ex' is never used.

Comment: Don't worry about the warning. Indeed,we declare `ex` as a Exception and we are not using it now, but you could show what went wrong using `MessageBox.Show("There was an error adding this entry to the key files."+ex.Message);`. I don't undestand what is the error with ToString.I've just tried it and gives me no compilation error. Try to change it to `string newTime=DateTime.Now.ToString()` and check you have no typos.

Comment: I tried that as well before submitting the question, even copy and pasted it. The intellisense wants to use it but the I get the red squiggly under ToString.

Comment: Just to try, replace that line with `string newTime="01/01/01 00:00:00;"`

Comment: Thank you sir, that is the solution. Much appreciated!